# Positioning in CSS

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I 've created a site using Dreamweaver, and all my images have absolute position with % metrics. it expands proportionally on wider screens, but everytime I try to resize and shrink browser window it just becomes a mess with all the images fallen in one narrow window. How can I rebuild my design so it shrinks in a browser window in a way that when it is too small for an element, it just wouldn't fit. Do I have to use fixed pos-ing or any other type of pos-ing? Whats the usual way web designers do the sites?
P.S. my site contains text and abs. images, as well as fixed image that scrolls with the screen. What should I use to keep it that way but make a decent view in all screen sizes?

Comment: No, you have to to trash it and start again without Dreamweaver. Generated code is the worst kind of code.

Comment: I would suggest you start with your mobile design/layout first, and then scale up by spacing out your elements and/or adding more content using media queries at different sensible break points (tablet, laptop screen, desktop monitor, etc).

Comment: looks like you are trying to add mobile responsiveness to some old site that was not designed to be that way in the first place.. in these cases your best to start anew since you asked how.

Comment: Absolute positioning is pretty non-responsive by nature...even with % values. There are **much** better methods of page layout than positioning..I'd argue tables are better than positioning...but that's another argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries or place a min-width on either the body or the element in question. For example placing min-width:900px on the body will stop the entire body from re-sizing below 900px width. (Note: That is not the responsive way to do things. Media queries are a much better practice)